# Problem with Apple Push Notification service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I tried to set the push notification on my app iPhone.
I created the certificate and then I used the apns php library on my web server to create the notify, but this is the error:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means that your apns certificate has been revoked. You can regenerate a new certificate and then try again.

Comment: :) also using openssl utility, you can check that ssl handcheck is working properly. Use following command for that.   $ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem